# Download file and upload to FTP directly

Tags: php, csv, pdo, ftp

I have a little question.. I have a page with PHP Datatables installed, so I downloaded the rows which are in the datatable to a .csv file, but now I want that .csv file to be uploaded to an FTP path automatically..

So the first thing that came up in my mind was to change the download path, but that was kind off impossible to do.

Second thing was to made a form where you can upload the downloaded file. But now I dont know how to send that directly to the FTP..

Maybe someone can help me?!

Comment: Did you already manage to automate the part where you download the CSV file? How? If you're using a bash script you can just use `ftp -u [server_name] [file_to_upload]`

Comment: I just have to click on a button, that directly download the .csv file.. I just have to make a PHP script

Comment: You will want to save the `.csv` file on your server and then upload it instead of downloading it. take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Comment: So maybe what you want is a second button on that page that says "upload to FTP" and when pressed uploads the file to an FTP server? With PHP code (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) ?

Comment: Thnx man, maybe I could try that...